# getting marker-symbol with $.ajax from *.geojson file

Tags: ajax, leaflet, geojson, marker

I'm using markers with data from a *.geojson file. It works with

```
var Symbol = L.icon({iconUrl: 'sonne.png'});
...
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);}

$.ajax(myGeojsonFile).done(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    // Symbol = L.icon ({iconUrl: feature.properties.marker-symbol});
    L.geoJson(data, 
            {pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng, {icon: Symbol});},
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);
    });
```

But I want to set the marker-symbol in the *.geojson file. I altered the *.geojson file with a geojson editor, therefoere it schould be correct.
But it does not work, if I try to set the marker symbol with the "//-line" in the code above. How to fix this?
Thanks for thinking about the problem!
Gruss, wonk

Answer (score 0):

it works with this:

```
   $.ajax(overlay).done(function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    L.geoJson(data, 
            {pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {return L.marker(latlng, {icon:  L.icon({iconUrl: feature.properties.markerSymbol})});},
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature}).addTo(map);
    });
```

The property "marker-symbol" in the *.geojson file must not have a "-"character!
Gruss, wonk